¿Cómo puedo agregar otros criterios de reemplazo en este Transliterator?
He definido este Transliterator que me quita las tildes en el contenido, pero dejando las letras:
$transL = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);

En ese sentido funciona del modo esperado, convirtiendo cadenas como:
San Odilón de Cluny

A:
SanOdilondeCluny

Mi pregunta es, si es posible modificar ese Transliterator, o crear otro, que haga lo del anterior (quitar las tildes) pero que además reemplace ciertos carácteres.
Por ejemplo, dada esta cadena:
Sermón 10, sobre San Juan Bautista. PL 142, 1019-1020

Quede convertida a:
Sermon-10-sobre-San-Juan-Bautista_PL-142-1019-1020

Se trataría básicamente de cambiar las comas, los espacios en blanco y los dos puntos por - y los puntos cambiarlos por _.
¿Es posible hacerlo con Transliterator y de ser posible, cuáles serían las reglas que debo aplicar?

Según el criterio:

Se trataría básicamente de cambiar las comas, los espacios en blanco y
los dos puntos por - y los puntos cambiarlos por _

Son 4 reglas...
[, ] > "-": Comas con espacio (, ), por guiones (-).
[\u0020] > "-": Espacios en blanco ( ) por guiones (-).
[:Colon:] > "-": Dos puntos (:) por guiones (-).
[. ] > "_": puntos con espacio (. ) por guiones bajos (_).
Lo que quedaría como
Transliterator::createFromRules('
    :: Any-Latin; #Conversion a Latin
    :: Latin-ASCII; #Conversion ASCII
    :: NFD; #Normalization Form D - Decomposed
    :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; #Elimina marcas de acento decompuestos
    :: NFC; #Normalization Form C - Composed
    [, ] > "-"; #Comas
    [\u0020] > "-"; #Espacios
    [:Colon:] > "-"; #Dos puntos
    [. ] > "_"; #Puntos
',Transliterator::FORWARD);

Curioso, no sabía eso que de que se le puede dar FORWARD o REVERSE :3
Recordar, eliminar los comentarios en los que trato de explicar las reglas. NFD y NFC son algo más largas de explicar, pero NFD descompone los caracteres en sus partes y NFC los compone.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226903/icu-what-does-nfd-and-nfc-mean

Por cierto, dejaré comentado dada la inexperiencia. No se si es mejor esto, aplicar más reglas. O usar alguna función de replace de manera separada. Igual depende del uso que le quieres dar supongo.

Hola. Por algún motivo, el objeto que se crea con este código es NULL y por tanto no funciona.
